# |error: conversion from 'int' to non-scalar type 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' requested|

Tags: c++

I'm a complete noob, short-time lurker, first time poster.

I'm trying to build something for school, basing myself on prior builds, but it ends up having a ton of errors that I can't seem to root out, especially regarding the use of `string`s, the `strcpy`s, and the `const` constructor.

Here is my cpp code:

```
#include "taxi.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

Taxi::Taxi(){
    int interno = 0;
    string marca = 'Marca';
    string patente = 'AA 00 AA';
    string Propietario = 'Apellido, Nombre';
    int chofer = 0;
    fadia = 1;
    fames = 1;
    fanio = 1970;
    fbdia = 1;
    fbmes = 1;
    fbanio = 1970;
    double tel = 0;
}

Taxi::Taxi(int inter, string marc, string pat, string prop, int ch, int dia_a,
    int dia_b, int mes_a, int mes_b, int anio_a, int anio_b, double te){
        
    int interno = inter;
    string marca = marc;
    string patente = pat;
    string propietario = prop;
    int chofer = ch;
    fadia = dia_a;
    fames = mes_a;
    fanio = anio_a;
    fbdia = dia_b;
    fbmes = mes_b;
    fbanio = anio_b;
    double tel = te;
}

Taxi::~Taxi(){
    cout<<"Destructor Activado. Fin del Programa."<<endl;
}

void Taxi::setPropietario(string prop){
    strcpy(propietario, prop);
}

void Taxi::setChofer(int ch){
    int chofer = ch;
}

void Taxi::imprimir(){
    cout<<"Chofer en Servicio: "<<"\n   -"<<chofer<<"\n  -"<<propietario <<"\n  -"<<tel<<endl;
    cout<<"Vehiculo en Servicio: "<<"\n   -"<<marca<<"\n  -"<<patente<<endl;
    cout<<"Fecha de alta: "<<fadia<<"/"<<fames<<"/"<<fanio<<endl;
    cout<<"Fecha de baja: "<<fbdia<<"/"<<fbmes<<"/"<<fbanio<<endl;
}
```

and my header

```
#ifndef TAXI_H
#define TAXI_H
#endif // TAXI_H
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
    
class Taxi{
    private:
        int interno;
        std::string marca;
        std::string patente;
        std::string propietario;
        int chofer;
        int fadia;
        int fames;
        int fanio;
        int fbdia;
        int fbmes;
        int fbanio;
        double tel;

    public:
        Taxi();
        Taxi(int inter, std::string marc, std::string pat, std::string prop, int ch, int dia_a,
            int dia_b, int mes_a, int mes_b, int anio_a, int anio_b, double te);
        Taxi(const Taxi &);
        ~Taxi();

        void setPropietario(std::string prop);
        void setChofer(int inter);
        void imprimir();
        void imprimirtaxi();
};
```

Comment: C-style string functions and C++ std::string's don't match well.

Comment: Unrelated, but a couple of things of note: 1) in `taxi.h` your `#endif` should be at the end of the file, and 2) your `Taxi` constructors as well as `Taxi::setChofer` are setting variables local to the function, not the object's member variables.

Comment: Also, it looks as if you've pasted code into your cpp file. You have two definitions of `Taxi::Taxi()`